# Could not find method onClickcrea(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick

Tags: java, android

I basically can't understand when i click on the onClick="onClickcrea" it doesn't works. I also tried changing the name of the onClick but it doesn't matter. I get this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClickcrea(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'onClickcrea'
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:325)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

here is my xml activity:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="purgimon.pt11_marc_purgimon.Registra"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/botoUsuari"
                android:id="@+id/NUsuari"
                android:layout_weight="0.11"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/botoCorreu"
                android:id="@+id/Correu"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:id="@+id/editText3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="34dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/botoTelefon"
                android:id="@+id/Correu"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:id="@+id/editText4" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.03"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/botoContrasenya"
                android:id="@+id/Contrasenya"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.05" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.57">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editTextContra" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.03" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/botoRepeteixContrasenya"
                android:id="@+id/ContrasenyRepetida"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editTextContraR" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/Botosexe"
                android:id="@+id/Sexe"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.31"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/BotoHome"
                android:id="@+id/Home"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_weight="0.08" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/botoDona"
                android:id="@+id/Dona"
                android:layout_weight="0.12"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_marginLeft="150dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/boto2Ajuda"
                android:id="@+id/AjudaRegistra"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:onClick="ajuda"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/botoCrea"
                android:id="@+id/onClickcrea"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
                android:onClick="onClickcrea" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And here my Java code:

```
public class Registra extends AppCompatActivity {
    String contrasenya1;
    String contrasenya2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registra);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_principal, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void ajuda(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Ajuda.class);
            startActivity(intent);


    }

    public void onClickcrea (View view){
        EditText textContra1 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextContra);
        contrasenya1 = textContra1.getText().toString();
        EditText textContra2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextContraR);
        contrasenya2 = textContra2.getText().toString();

        Toast missatge = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Les contrasenyes han de coincidir!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        missatge.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is why I never use the `onClick` attribute. Setting an `OnClickListener` directly in code never fails and doesn't rely on any magical reflection trickery, which can be broken by a variety of things (like Proguard).

Comment: Does `ajuda(View)` work by clicked the button`AjudaRegistra`?

Comment: no, it doesn't. My android application has three activities: my main activity called "activity_principal", "activity_registra" and "ajuda". The first two activities have an "ajuda" button and  only this works in my onClick method in my main activity. Obviously i checked that the method and the onClick have the same name and also i changed the ajuda's onClick name to try if it works, but any change solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would suggest using a onClickListener instead of the XML attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The method defined in the android:onClick could not be found in the activity that the view was inflated in.
The most common mistakes for this error are method name typo and wrong layout inflation.

As stated in other comments you should rather use onClickListeners.